# Browse autocomplete results without arrows in Sublime

Tags: sublimetext2, sublimetext3

I'm using Sublime Text 3, and I am trying to not use arrows for anything. However I can't seem to scroll through different results of autocomplete or Ctrl+P without the arrows.

Any suggestions? Thanks!

Comment: You can make two new custom keybindings using the move (by lines) command and the forward param.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You probably want something like this in your keymaps file:

```
// navigation with tab in autocomplete popup
{ "keys": ["tab"], "command": "move", "args": {"by": "lines", "forward": true}, "context": [{ "key": "auto_complete_visible" }] },
{ "keys": ["shift+tab"], "command": "move", "args": {"by": "lines", "forward": false}, "context": [{ "key": "auto_complete_visible" }] },

// navigation with tab in overlay
{ "keys": ["tab"], "command": "move", "args": {"by": "lines", "forward": true}, "context": [{ "key": "overlay_visible", "operator": "equal", "operand": true } ] },
{ "keys": ["shift+tab"], "command": "move", "args": {"by": "lines", "forward": false}, "context": [{ "key": "overlay_visible", "operator": "equal", "operand": true } ] },
```

Comment: Thanks Philipp! works great for the autocomplete, but not for the Ctrl+P options. Any ideas of why this might be? Thanks again!

Comment: Sure @Sara! Sorry, i overlooked this when i first answered!

Comment: I'm so sorry! I didn't realize you edited your answer. With "navigation in overlay" it works! Thank you very much Philipp, and sorry for the misunderstanding :)