# Go through results of Ctrl + P without arrows

Tags: sublimetext, sublimetext3

I'm using Sublime Text 3, and I am trying to not use arrows for anything. However I can't seem to scroll through different results of

> Ctrl + P

without the arrows.

Any suggestions? Thanks!

Comment: Would like to know how to do this too.

Comment: Well.. you simply type in the suggested result until it's highlighted?

Comment: Sergey, that sometimes takes too much typing, if the only difference between the files is the ending (.h and .cpp)

Comment: Scrolling with mouse and clicking?

Comment: You asked a similar question 2 days ago and the accepted answer and  my comment suggestion both works for me. Have you tried using different keys?

Comment: Your answer to the other question works, but only to go through the autocomplete options. It does not work for this particular problem, so I decided to divide it into two different questions. I am using different key bindings than the ones you suggested, but I still have the same problem.

Comment: Ok, for me it works both in autocomplete and in ctrl+p in linux, anyhow that's not my answer :p

Comment: The answer in this other post works:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29256615/browse-autocomplete-results-without-arrows-in-sublime/29266514?noredirect=1#comment46750885_29266514

Answer (score 1):

Well, you could just leverage the fuzzy completion of Sublime Text by entering `somefile .cpp` or `somefile .h` (notice the space).